# How to center an image .logo via css?

Tags: css, center, graphical-logo, impresspages

I made over the content management a image as logo, I tried to center it in many ways, also replaced some floats before. its just impossible.

This is the untouched content of style.css from the exensivefree theme, i hope this was the right place at all:

```
header {
width:100%; 
margin:auto auto; 
z-index:101; 
padding:7px 0 12px 0; 
}

h1 {
display:inline-block; 
z-index:100;
}

.logo {
margin:25px 0px 10px 0;   
font-size: 24px; 
line-height:30px; 
font-weight: bold;
}

nav { }
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or some example site.

Comment: If the logo has position:relative you can use margin:0 auto;

Comment: I've tried text-align:center and it has worked.

Comment: `margin:25px 0px 10px 0;` -> `margin: 25px auto 10px auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the element a fixed width and set the margins to auto.

```
.logo {
  width:100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This makes the browser calculate equal margins to the left and right of the element, and therefore placing it in the centre of the page.